# 'expected an indent block'

Tags: python, block, indentation

I get 'expected an ident block' after the colon on the line: def StartGame(username):
It comes upp red for the rest of the line, and being new to programming i am unsure what i am doing wrong. Thank you on advance :)

```
def StartGame(username):
  print("This game is all about Trading and Adventuring.")
  time.sleep(0.51)
  print("This is what is in your inventory: %s" % Inventory)
  time.sleep(1)
  print("As you go around, you will start to lose hunger. You will need to buy food along the way.")
  time.sleep(1)
  print("You have %s Health Points (HP)" % UserHunger)
  TO.SetRandName()
```

Comment: 4 spaces for an indent, you only did 1 or 2, that's why, when it tells you the it expects an indent, it's because you need to have a 4 space indent

Comment: @Infamouslyuseless: Python actually doesn't care how big your indents are. You can even mix and match indent sizes in a single file, though it's a horrible idea to do so.

Comment: @user2357112 i know, but usually people do 4 spaces, or hit tab, which does the same, because it looks neater and easier to understand kinda thing if you know what i mean?

Comment: @Infamouslyuseless: That's what people usually do, but your comment said that Python would complain if you used a different indent size. Python doesn't care. (Also, hitting Tab isn't equivalent to 4 spaces unless you specifically instruct your text editor to insert 4 spaces instead of a tab.)

Comment: @user2357112 well with eclipse pydev i think tab automatically does it, because i didn't tell it to and it automatically does 4 spaces when i hit tab...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing tabs and spaces. Use 4 spaces for indentation:

```
def StartGame(username):
    print("This game is all about Trading and Adventuring.")
    time.sleep(0.51)
    print("This is what is in your inventory: %s" % Inventory)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("As you go around, you will start to lose hunger. You will need to buy food along the way.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("You have %s Health Points (HP)" % UserHunger)
    TO.SetRandName()
```

Also see [PEP-8 indentation paragraph](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).